# Page reload or change attribute going null JSF Prime

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have an application and in every page reload or page change, my "id" property of "logAtual" var going null.

But it's a SessionScoped and I not set explicitly the value.

I start this var with a p:remoteCommand, and call the p:remoteCommand in document.ready().

Any ideia? Thanks!

PS:I'm using PrimeFaces 5 and JSF 2.2

Comment: There's too much noise in your code. Reduce the code sample (especially the markup) to the minimum sample code sufficient to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define getter and setter for variable logAtual inside your backing bean.

Try to add following methods to UsuarioController:

```
public LogAcesso getLogAtual(){
   return logAtual;
}

public void setLogAtual(LogAcesso logAtual){
   this.logAtual=logAtual;
}
```